# Simple jQuery Popup with no overlay that opens on the click of a button and closes on the click of a cross

Tags: javascript, jquery

A simple search on Google for popup scripts brings out thousands of results for popup plugins.. But I believe something this simple shouldnt need a plugin.

I want a simple popup script with no overlay that does basically 3 things:

1. Opens on the click of a button
2. Closes on the click of a cross
3. Is centered on the screen and is fixed

   ```
   <div class="member-pop" id="member-pop1">

      <a class="member-close1 cross"><img src="img/pop/pop-cross.png"  
     alt="Close" /></a>  <! -- This will close Popup -->

    <p>Content inside popup</p>

   </div>
   ```

What I have done so far

```
 $('.pop-member1').click(function() {
            $('#member-pop1').show();
        });
        $('.cross').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
```

This achieves 1 and 2. Number 3 still not achieved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#member-pop1" ).dialog();

<div id="member-pop1" title="My dialog">
  <p>This is where you show the content. Click on cross to close me!</p>
</div>
```

Makes use of jquery ui dialog.